# Active admin controller testing with ActiveSupport::TestCase

Tags: unit-testing, testing, activeadmin, testcase

I've defined my own controllers and member_actions for some resources in Active Admin and now I have no idea how test them with ActiveSupport::TestCase.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

(I'm using [mocha](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/#Rails) for the stub. If you're not, you'll need to find another way to stub the authentication, or otherwise actually log in as an admin user)

```
require 'test_helper'

class AdminUserControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    # Creates a reference to the admin controller
    @controller = ::Admin::UsersController.new 

    # Prevents checking for a valid user session (pretends we're logged in)
    @controller.stubs(:authenticate_active_admin_user)
  end

  test "should ..." do 
    # ... the test ...
  end
end
```

Comment: +1, however the OP asked for `ActiveSupport::TestCase` which means unit tests.